# Excel Formula to get the result of a web query

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following Excel 2016 sheet:

```
**First Name                 Calc                           Result**
Richard     https://api.genderize.io/?name=richard
Arvin       https://api.genderize.io/?name=arvin
```

If I paste https://api.genderize.io/?name=richard in a browser I get:

```
  {"name":"richard","gender":"male","probability":0.99,"count":101928}
```

For https://api.genderize.io/?name=arvin, I get:

```
  {"name":"arvin","gender":"male","probability":0.98,"count":1602}
```

How can I automate these calculations with an Excel formula?

Desired result would be:

[result picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRbQA.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [WEBSERVICE()](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-webservice-function) function, with the value from your CALC column as the argument.

Comment: Amazing, I was not aware of this function, thank you very much for your help! Marked as answer.